# SWT Eclipse: Add a menu option to the left of Quick access search box

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, swt, eclipse-rcp

I tried debugging following code and found "SearchField" as element id for Quick access search box but when used in plugin.xml nothing is shown on UI:

```
    IWorkbenchWindow workbenchWindow = PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getActiveWorkbenchWindow();
    if (workbenchWindow instanceof WorkbenchWindow) {
        MTrimBar topTrim = ((WorkbenchWindow) workbenchWindow).getTopTrim();
    }
```

I tried using above found element id in plugin.xml as follows:

```
<extension
     point="org.eclipse.ui.menus">     
   <menuContribution
         locationURI="toolbar:SearchField">
      <toolbar
            id="org.eclipse.ui.examples.contributions.contributedTrim">
         <command
               commandId="org.eclipse.ui.examples.contributions.item2"
               id="textMode"
               label="Text Mode"
               tooltip="Text Mode">
         </command>
      </toolbar>
   </menuContribution>
```

Any pointers would be useful

Comment: Have a look at https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/366870/

Answer (score 1):

'SearchField' is the ID of the Quick Access **tool control**, not the toolbar.
It is placed in the main toolbar. So the placement should be as below

```
toolbar:main?before=SearchField
```

Hope this helps.

Hint: Play with [Model Spy](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/e4-spies) for easy identification of any UI component description and its placement in eclipse UI.
[image]

Comment: I used the locationURI provided by you but still the issue persists. I found that there is a "Spacer Glue" element added before SearchField which is causing this issue.

Comment: Hi, I found it should be one of below based on my existing usage. Try these:  "toolbar:main?before=SearchField" or  "toolbar:main?after=PerspectiveSpacer" or "toolbar:main?after=Spacer Glue"

Comment: Also, make sure to clear the workspace on application launching whenever checking the new UI change. Many times only after clearing the workspace the changes come to visible.

Comment: I tried with above URI's. It works fine on site build.  But when opening RCP for first time, it shows the menu in Left toolbar beside search button. Afterwards it takes it original position to right of Quick Access bar.

Comment: Can you please tell which one of the above URIs worked for you? Also, at the startup try to reset the perspective (activePage.resetPerspective()) on the postWindowOpen of WorkbenchWindowAdvisor so that the UI is refreshed with appropriate component location.

Comment: I added below URI. It added the toolbar item to the right of Quick access box.
`toolbar:org.eclipse.ui.main.toolbar?before=PerspectiveSwitcher`

Also, I tried  (activePage.resetPerspective()) on the postWindowOpen, but still didn't get the expected result